# R : Pivot hourly data to columns

Tags: r, pivot

I am pretty new to r and I am trying to manipulate bus schedule data. I would like to display the times following the picture attached [image: here].

I managed to go from 1. to 2. but I am now struggling to get to 3.

Here is my code so far :

```
#1
timetable <- as.data.frame(c("11:34","11:46","12:12","13:16","14:45","15:54","16:22"))
colnames(timetable) <- 'time'

#2
library(stringr)
new.timetable <- str_split_fixed(timetable$time,":",2) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(new.timetable) <- c('Hours', 'Minutes')

#3 ??
```

Is there a way to place Hours as columns and to get the minutes as the data under it ?

Thank you very much for your help.
Best,

Answer (score 0):

Do this serve your purpose?

```
#I have added one value to your timetable object
timetable <- as.data.frame(c("11:34","11:46","12:12","13:16","14:45","15:54","16:22", "11:47")) # added one value

library(tidyverse)
#3.
new.timetable %>% 
  group_by(Hours) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols=id, names_from = Hours, values_from = Minutes, values_fn = list) %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  unnest(1:6)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`  `16` 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 34    12    16    45    54    22   
2 46    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 47    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```